# How to supply external metrics into HPA?

Tags: kubernetes, hpa

**Problem setting.** Suppose I have 2 pods, A and B. I want to be able to dynamically scale pod A based on some arbitrary number from some arbitrary source. Suppose that pod B is such a source: for example, it can have an HTTP server with an endpoint which responds with the number of desired replicas of pod A at the moment of request. Or maybe it is an ES server or a SQL DB (does not matter).

**Question.** What kubernetes objects do I need to define to achieve this (apart from HPA)? What configuration should HPA have to know that it needs to look up B for current metric? How should API of B look like (or is there any constraints?)?

**Research I have made.** Unfortunately, the official documentation does not say much about it, apart from declaring that there is such a possibility. There are also two repositories, [one](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/custom-metrics-apiserver) with some go boilerplate code that I have trouble building and [another](https://github.com/zalando-incubator/kube-metrics-adapter) one that has no usage instructions whatsoever (though allegedly does fulfil the "external metrics over HTTP" requirement).

By having a look at the `.yaml` configs in those repositories, I have reached a conclusion that apart from `Deployment` and `Service` one needs to define an `APIService` object that registers the external or custom metric in the kubernetes API and links it with a normal service (where you would have your pod) and a handful of `ClusterRole` and `ClusterRoleBinding` objects. But there is no explanation about it. Also I could not even list existing APIServices with kubectl in my local cluster (of 1.15 version) like other objects.

Answer (score 5):

The easiest way will be to feed metrics into Prometheus (which is a commonly solved problem), and then setup a Prometheus-based HPA (also a commonly solved problem).

**1. Feed own metrics to Prometheus**

- Start with [Prometheus-Operator](https://github.com/helm/charts/tree/master/stable/prometheus-operator) to get the cluster itself monitored, and get access to `ServiceMonitor` objects. ServiceMonitors are pointers to services in the cluster. They let your pod's `/metrics` endpoint be discovered and scraped by a prometheus server.
- Write a pod that reads metrics from your 3rd party API and shows them in own `/metrics` endpoint. This will be the adapter between your API and Prometheus format. There are clients of course: https://github.com/prometheus/client_python#exporting
- Write a `Service` of type `ClusterIP` that represents your pod.
- Write a `ServiceMonitor` that points to a service.
- Query your custom metrics thru Prometheus dashboard to ensure this stage is done.

**2. Setup Prometheus-based HPA**

- Setup [Prometheus-Adapter](https://github.com/helm/charts/tree/master/stable/prometheus-adapter) and follow the HPA walkthrough.
- Or follow the guide https://github.com/stefanprodan/k8s-prom-hpa

This looks like a huge pile of work to get the HPA. However, only the adapter pod is a custom part here. Everything else is a standard stack setup in most of the clusters, and you will get many other use cases for it anyways.

Comment: Thank you for the effort of writing this down. However, while this answer provides a working workaround, this is not exactly what I am looking for. My question is about understanding the hard part of building this myself from ground up in Kubernetes. Nonetheless, thanks again

Comment: Note that if you want a service that responds with the number of desired replicas you need a custom Controller (or Operator), not the custom Metrics server. In HPA notation I don't see a way to query metric and put the resulting value directly to desired replicas.

Comment: Look at the https://github.com/operator-framework/operator-sdk. The operator instance can take num replicas from the outside and control accordingly. This is basically the same as writing a pod that can modify other deployments, without HPA.